# Where is the in AndroidManifest.xml defined logo used?

Tags: android, android-manifest, graphical-logo

My question is probably easy, but yet I cant find a satisfying answer anywhere...

For which purpose is the logo used that can be defined in AndroidManifest.xml (Android 4.0).
I know it can be used to replace the launcher Icon in ActionBar.
Are there any other positions (Market?) where it is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also when you long-press the home screen and it shows you the currently running programs; also for file representations of the apk; the Application list; the Apps panel; etc etc.

The market uses assets that you upload separately when publishing the app.

Comment: It's worth noting that other apps can retrieve a list of activities and their icons, as does the 'Application list' (launcher) .

Answer (score 0):

When submitting an app to the android market, you have to upload a 512x512 hi-res icon that it uses. The one specified in the manifest only refers to the one the app uses, located at res/drawable/icon.png